# wvMaxima Error: "Not Connected To Maxima" on Windows

Tags: windows, firewall

Whenever I try to do anything with it, [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) gives the error:

> Not Connected To Maxima

[I've looked around](http://www.google.ca/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=not+connected+to+maxima), but I couldn't figure out how to fix this on Windows. The only results I got were for Fedora. According to them, I think this may have something to do with the firewall, but I can't figure out what.

I even tried adding wvMaxima to the Windows Firewall exceptions list, but the same error comes up.

**UPDATE:** I'm now using ZoneAlarm, but I haven't checked to see if the problem remains.

I've also tried using Compatibility mode with Windows XP (and others), but to no avail.

Comment: Same problem here...